# How to access the speech engine with python

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I hear that there is a speech engine that will disregard any commands that you give it? i'm trying to make a program in python that you can tell it things. right now i'm using the windows 7 speech recognition but the problem is if i say something and if it misunderstands me and thinks its a command it runs that command. is there a way to access this speech engine in python and have it where it won't listen for those commands? i'm using pyspeech to listen for the user input.